# Assistance with Permutation Cipher (Columnar Transposition)

Tags: encryption, keys, permutation

I was wondering if someone could provide some assistance with understanding a permutation cipher.  I have both the cipher text as well as the plaintext but am having some difficulties trying to find the period (or key).  What are the steps to locate the key? This is the cipher text:
[image: Cipher Text]

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. This is off-topic here, you may get some hints in the comments. What is plaintext? Does it only columnar transpostion? What did you try?

Comment: https://www.litscape.com/word_tools/contains_only.php